# Проблема с анимацией fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-layout, android-animation

У меня есть активити с гугл картами, и к этой активити я хочу добавить фрагмент который по marker будет появляться анимировано с низу. Но это не работает почему-то. 
Вот мой главный класс:

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_main);




    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView2);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Map.this, "You have to accept to enjoy all app's services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(50.4294706, 30.5025214), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(50.4294706, 30.5025214);
     Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(MELBOURNE)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));



     fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragment= new FragmentImage();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fr_image, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();



        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                if (fragmentManager != null) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.animation_fragment_up,
                                    R.animator.animation_fragment_down,
                                    R.animator.animation_fragment_up,
                                    R.animator.animation_fragment_down)
                            .replace(R.id.fr_image, fragment
                            ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }

                Toast.makeText(Map.this,"SS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Xml главного активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView2" />

<fragment android:name="pc.dd.sex_startup.LogIn.Maps.FragmentImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fr_image"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_image"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</fragment>
```

И xml анимации:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueTo="1280"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:duration="300"/>
  </set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал все просто, создаем фрагмент -> делаем на главной активити `map.setOnMarkerCkickListener(new ...)` -> в событие пихаем создание фрагмента + анимация на появление.